# Bootstrap SUBMIT button not submitting - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

First I want to apologize if this question was already asked. However I am not able to resolve this issue. I don't know where to find the problem and why it does not print out when the form is filled. I have simple PHP file which takes data from form and should print it out on screen:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
//get data from form


$Title = $_POST['Title']; // title of case study
$Summary = $_POST['Summary']; // summary of case study
$WhatDid = $_POST['WhatDid']; // what did you do question
$Volunteering = $_POST['Volunteering'];
$Credit = $_POST['Credit-bearing'];
$Local = $_POST['Local-schools'];            // themes checkboxes
$Elderly = $_POST['Elderly'];
$Environmental = $_POST['Environmental'];
$Edinburgh = $_POST['Edinburgh'];
$Scotland = $_POST['Scotland'];
$UK = $_POST['UK'];                          // themes checboxes
$International = $_POST['International'];
$Online = $_POST['Online'];
$Other = $_POST['Other_theme'];              // themes checboxes
$Undergraduate = $_POST['Undergraduate'];    // cohort checboxes
$Masters = $_POST['Masters'];
$PhD = $_POST['PhD'];                        // cohort checboxes
$WhyDid = $_POST['WhyDid'];
$WhatWell = $_POST['WhatWell'];
$WhatDifferently = $_POST['WhatDifferently'];
$Scalability = $_POST['Scalability'];
$FurtherInfo = $_POST['FurtherInfo'];
$Location = $_POST['Location'];
$AuthorTitle = $_POST['title'];// authors title
$F_Name = $_POST['first_name'];
$L_Name = $_POST['last_name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Contactauthor = $_POST['contact'];
$Note1 = $_POST['note1'];
$Note2 = $_POST['note2'];
$Engagement = $_POST['engagement']; // date of engagement

echo nl2br(
    "This is a $Title, 
    \n this is a $Summary, 
    this is a  $WhatDid, 
    \n this is checkbox $Volunteering, 
    this is checkbox $Credit, 
    \n this is checkbox $Local, 
    this is checkbox $Elderly, 
    \n this is checkbox $Environmental, 
    this is checkbox $Edinburgh, 
    \n this is checkbox $Scotland, 
    this is checkbox $UK, 
    \n this is checkbox $International, 
    this is checkbox $Online, 
    \n this is other themes $Other, 
    this is an $Undergraduate, 
    \n this is a $Masters, 
    this is a $PhD,  
    \n this is why it was done: $WhyDid, 
    this is what went well: $WhatWell, 
    \n this is what could be done differently: $WhatDifferently, 
    Could it be scalable & transerable?: $Scalability,
    \n Additional information?: $FurtherInfo,
    Location of practice: $Location,
    \n this is an Author $AuthorTitle $F_Name $L_Name, email address: $Email  
    and he is contact: $Contactauthor, 
    \n this is a date of engagement $Engagement, 
    Author agrees with possible ammendments: $Note1, $Note2."
);
```

and then here is a html itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title> Submit Case Study</title>

<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // if Google is down, it looks to local file...
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("script src='js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'      type='text/javascript'/script"));
}
</script>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>-->

    <!-- script to clone author -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/clone-form-td.js"></script>

    <!-- Own stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- jQuery customized theme-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
        function toggle(id) {
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';    
        } else {                                                    
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    } //script to expand text field when
</script> 

<script>
$(function(){    
$("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"}); // datepicker
});
</script>

<style>
  .ui-datepicker {font-size:85%; } /* custom size of datepicker */
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="submit" action="PHP/submit-test.php" method="POST">

    <div class="main container">

        <p class="label1">Title *</p>
        <input class="textboxstyle" type="text" name="Title">
        <p class="help-block">Meaningful, short descriptive title</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">Summary *</p>
        <textarea name="Summary"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">Brief summary of what the engagement involved.</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">What did you do? *</p>
        <textarea name="WhatDid"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">Please give a description of the case study including the theme(s)/topics(s) it relates to (please see list overleaf). It would be helpful if this could include the stage of development (e.g. whether the practice is new or established). Please include links to key themes/topics .</p>
        <br>

        <div>
            <p class="label1">Links to key themes/topics *</p>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="Volunteering" name="Volunteering" value="YES"/> Volunteering<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id ="Credit-bearing" name="Credit-bearing" value="YES"/> Credit-bearing course<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Local-schools" name="Local-schools" value="YES"/> Working with local schools and / or young people<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Elderly" value="YES"/> Working with elderly people<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Environmental" value="YES"/> Environmental or sustainability<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Edinburgh" value="YES"/> Based in Edinburgh or the Lothians<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Scotland" value="YES"/> Based in Scotland (excluding Edinburgh or the Lothians)<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="UK" value="YES"/> Based in the UK<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="International" value="YES"/> Based internationally<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Online" value="YES"/> Online component<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('Other_theme')" name="Other"> Other<br/>
                <div id="other_theme" style="display:none;">
                <input type="text" class="singleline1" id="Other_theme" name="Other_theme" required="">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div>
        <p class="label1">Student cohort*</p>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Undergraduate" value="YES"> Undergraduate<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Masters" value="YES"> Postgraduate (Masters)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="PhD" value="YES"> Postgraduate (Research)<br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p class="label1">Why did you do it? *</p>
        <textarea name="WhyDid"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">A brief outline of the reasons behind the practice described - its purpose and benefits. What change was it intended to make or problem was it designed to solve?</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">What went well? *</p>
        <textarea name="WhatWell"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">A brief outline of what worked well for you/ your organisation. What were the highlights? Did you receive any positive feedback?</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">What might you have done differently? *</p>
        <textarea name="WhatDifferently"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">A brief outline of any particular challenges faced and how these were addressed. Please also say if you are planning any changes or further developments.</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">Scalability and transferability *</p>
        <textarea name="Scalability"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">Is this practice scalable and transferable? What is the potential for it being expanded and/or run elsewhere in the University? A brief outline of workload commitments in setting up and maintaining the practice would also be useful.</p>
        <br>   

        <p class="label1">Further information *</p>
        <textarea name="FurtherInfo"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">e.g. website or publications, materials used, presentation slides, screen shots, testimonials. A couple of quotes from community members, students or staff illustrating the case study would be particularly useful.</p>
        <br>  

        <p class="label1">Location of practice *</p>
        <textarea name="Location"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">Name of community partner, academic School/ support service involved (if applicable).</p>
        <br> 
<div id="author1" class="clonedInput">
<p id="author" class="label1">Author </p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_title textboxstyle">
        <p id="help-block-title" class="help-block-title">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn textboxstyle">
        <p id="help-block-fn" class="help-block-fn">First Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_ln textboxstyle">
        <p id="help-block-ln" class="help-block-ln">Last Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="abc@example.com" class="input_email textboxstyle">
        <p id="help-block-email" class="help-block-email">Email</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
        <input id="contact" name="contact" type="checkbox" value="YES" class="contact">
        <p id="help-block-checkbox" class="help-block-checkbox">Contact</p>
    </div>

   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
        <input id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add author">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
        <input id="btnDel" name="btnDel" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove author">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

        <p class="label1">Date*</p>
        <div>
        <div class="datebox">
            <input id="date" class="date" name="engagement">
            <p class="help-block">When the engagement activity took place</p>
        </div>    
        </div>
        <div>
        <p class="label1">Note for authors</p>
            <div>
            <input name="note1" type="checkbox" value="YES"><p class="prg-text"> 1) The full case study (in this template format) will be included on a public wiki database.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input name="note2" type="checkbox" value="YES"><p class="prg-text"> 2) The Student Community Engagement team will produce a summary version of each case study suitable for an external and internal audience. Authors will be asked to approve these public versions of their case studies before they are made available on open websites. These case studies will be available as .pdf downloads and other formats suitable for printing and inclusion in publications, as web pages and for presentations. These will be available on the public section of the Student Community Engagement website and linked to other key sites.</p> 
            </div>

        <p class="help-block">The case study will be used in two ways and consent of author is required for both.</p>    
        </div>  

        <br><br>

<input class="submit btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</div>  

</form>
</body>
```

Any idea will be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: create a jsfiddle for this

Comment: Please change form name. There is two elements with same name submit. `<submit>` & `<form>`

Comment: Couple of tips. 1: Name your `PHP` variables the same as the `name=""` in your html. 2: when debugging your code, strip out everything to the bare minimum then keep adding/testing it until it breaks - then you find your culprit. 3: Don't post ALL of your code on SO, strip out the irrelevant parts, you really don't need to post code for 31 bits of data. The less (and more relevant) code you post, the easier it is for someone to help you, and you may even spot the error in the process of sanitising your code for SO.

Comment: I meant a simple example so i don't have to fill out a huge form to test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problem in this code.

```
.
.
<div>
  <p class="label1">Links to key themes/topics *</p>
  <div class="checkbox">
      .
            .
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('Other_theme')" name="Other" > Other<br/>
      <div id="other_theme" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" class="singleline1" id="Other_theme" name="Other_theme" required="">
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
.
.
```

Either you click `checkbox 'Other'` or not, `'Other_theme' textbox` will be required. So, remove '`required`' attribute from `'Other_theme' textbox`. You thinking, that `<div>` is hidden so, it will not ask `required` field. But, actually this is not happening.

Validate it through jquery. Write `onsubmit="return checkValidation();"` in your `<form>` tag too (as below) for validating it at end. One more thing i added in your code is add `value="Other"` in `'Other_theme' textbox`. Please see my code minutely.

**Updated Code.**

```
<form action="PHP/submit-test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkValidation();">
.
.
<div>
  <p class="label1">Links to key themes/topics *</p>
  <div class="checkbox">
      .
            .
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('Other_theme')" name="Other" value="Other"> Other<br/>
      <div id="other_theme" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" class="singleline1" id="Other_theme" name="Other_theme">
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
.
.
```

Add This too in your **.js** file.

```
<script>
function checkValidation() 
{
        var OtherVal = $("input[name='Other']:checked").val();
        if(OtherVal == 'Other')
        {
            alert("Please Fill Other Theme");
            return false;
        }
}
</script>
```

**In Addition to user's requirement on Jan 19.**

```
<script>
function checkValidation() 
{
        var OtherVal = $("input[name='Other']:checked").val();
        var OtherThemeValue = $("#Other_theme").val();
        if(OtherVal == 'Other' && OtherThemeValue=="")
        {
            alert("Please Fill Other Theme");
            return false;
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was about to post in here that error was causing 'required=""' in input tag as you described above. Also function is very helpful. Great work

Comment: I'm Pleased. *Happy Coding.* Thanks @Vlad

Comment: one more thing. I have just noticed that even I put some entry into expanded input field I am still prompted to fill the field. Any suggestion on how to fix that. I am sure it is something simple.

Comment: Check My Edited Answer @ section **In Addition to user's requirement on Jan 19.** @Vlad

Comment: I have updated script accordingly, but still getting alert to "fill other theme". ..:( any idea why?

Comment: @Vlad: Post your updated **js** code in comment along with this code `<div id="other_theme" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" class="singleline1" id="Other_theme" name="Other_theme">
      </div>`

Comment: <div id="other_theme" style="display:none;"> <input type="text" class="singleline1" id="Other_theme" name="Other_theme"> </div>       <script>
            function checkValidation() 
        {
        var OtherVal = $("input[name='Other']:checked").val();
        var OtherThemeValue = $("#Other_theme").val();
        if(OtherVal == 'Other' && OtherThemeValue == "")
        {
            alert("Please Fill Other Theme");
            return false;
        }
        }
        </script>

Comment: I have renamed and assigned id of Input field to var OtherThemeValue and it works :) thank you again. I have used one name for div and input field and I think that was causing problem. Thank you again

Comment: I know it will work. See, please don't get panic when something doesn't work. There is nothing impossible in this evergreen planet which can't be done. So, my suggestion is to see your/my code minutely to understand the basic functionality. *Glad it worked* @Vlad

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="submit" action="PHP/submit-test.php" method="POST">
<input class="submit btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

There is two elements with same name. So change name of anyone element.

```
<form name="form1" action="PHP/submit-test.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: same result, not working after change. any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Update your html code to this

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title> Submit Case Study</title>

<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // if Google is down, it looks to local file...
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("script src='js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'      type='text/javascript'/script"));
}
</script>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>-->

    <!-- script to clone author -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/clone-form-td.js"></script>

    <!-- Own stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- jQuery customized theme-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
        function toggle(id) {
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';    
        } else {                                                    
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    } //script to expand text field when
</script> 

<script>
$(function(){    
$("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"}); // datepicker
});
</script>

<style>
  .ui-datepicker {font-size:85%; } /* custom size of datepicker */
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="PHP/submit-test.php" method="POST">

    <div class="main container">

        <p class="label1">Title *</p>
        <input class="textboxstyle" type="text" name="Title">
        <p class="help-block">Meaningful, short descriptive title</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">Summary *</p>
        <textarea name="Summary"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">Brief summary of what the engagement involved.</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">What did you do? *</p>
        <textarea name="WhatDid"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">Please give a description of the case study including the theme(s)/topics(s) it relates to (please see list overleaf). It would be helpful if this could include the stage of development (e.g. whether the practice is new or established). Please include links to key themes/topics .</p>
        <br>

        <div>
            <p class="label1">Links to key themes/topics *</p>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="Volunteering" name="Volunteering" value="YES"/> Volunteering<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id ="Credit-bearing" name="Credit-bearing" value="YES"/> Credit-bearing course<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Local-schools" name="Local-schools" value="YES"/> Working with local schools and / or young people<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Elderly" value="YES"/> Working with elderly people<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Environmental" value="YES"/> Environmental or sustainability<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Edinburgh" value="YES"/> Based in Edinburgh or the Lothians<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Scotland" value="YES"/> Based in Scotland (excluding Edinburgh or the Lothians)<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="UK" value="YES"/> Based in the UK<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="International" value="YES"/> Based internationally<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Online" value="YES"/> Online component<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('Other_theme')" name="Other"> Other<br/>
                <div id="other_theme" style="display:none;">
                <input type="text" class="singleline1" id="Other_theme" name="Other_theme" required="">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div>
        <p class="label1">Student cohort*</p>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Undergraduate" value="YES"> Undergraduate<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Masters" value="YES"> Postgraduate (Masters)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="PhD" value="YES"> Postgraduate (Research)<br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p class="label1">Why did you do it? *</p>
        <textarea name="WhyDid"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">A brief outline of the reasons behind the practice described - its purpose and benefits. What change was it intended to make or problem was it designed to solve?</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">What went well? *</p>
        <textarea name="WhatWell"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">A brief outline of what worked well for you/ your organisation. What were the highlights? Did you receive any positive feedback?</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">What might you have done differently? *</p>
        <textarea name="WhatDifferently"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">A brief outline of any particular challenges faced and how these were addressed. Please also say if you are planning any changes or further developments.</p>
        <br>

        <p class="label1">Scalability and transferability *</p>
        <textarea name="Scalability"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">Is this practice scalable and transferable? What is the potential for it being expanded and/or run elsewhere in the University? A brief outline of workload commitments in setting up and maintaining the practice would also be useful.</p>
        <br>   

        <p class="label1">Further information *</p>
        <textarea name="FurtherInfo"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">e.g. website or publications, materials used, presentation slides, screen shots, testimonials. A couple of quotes from community members, students or staff illustrating the case study would be particularly useful.</p>
        <br>  

        <p class="label1">Location of practice *</p>
        <textarea name="Location"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block">Name of community partner, academic School/ support service involved (if applicable).</p>
        <br> 
<div id="author1" class="clonedInput">
<p id="author" class="label1">Author </p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_title textboxstyle">
        <p id="help-block-title" class="help-block-title">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn textboxstyle">
        <p id="help-block-fn" class="help-block-fn">First Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_ln textboxstyle">
        <p id="help-block-ln" class="help-block-ln">Last Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="abc@example.com" class="input_email textboxstyle">
        <p id="help-block-email" class="help-block-email">Email</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
        <input id="contact" name="contact" type="checkbox" value="YES" class="contact">
        <p id="help-block-checkbox" class="help-block-checkbox">Contact</p>
    </div>

   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
        <input id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add author">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
        <input id="btnDel" name="btnDel" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove author">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

        <p class="label1">Date*</p>
        <div>
        <div class="datebox">
            <input id="date" class="date" name="engagement">
            <p class="help-block">When the engagement activity took place</p>
        </div>    
        </div>
        <div>
        <p class="label1">Note for authors</p>
            <div>
            <input name="note1" type="checkbox" value="YES"><p class="prg-text"> 1) The full case study (in this template format) will be included on a public wiki database.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input name="note2" type="checkbox" value="YES"><p class="prg-text"> 2) The Student Community Engagement team will produce a summary version of each case study suitable for an external and internal audience. Authors will be asked to approve these public versions of their case studies before they are made available on open websites. These case studies will be available as .pdf downloads and other formats suitable for printing and inclusion in publications, as web pages and for presentations. These will be available on the public section of the Student Community Engagement website and linked to other key sites.</p> 
            </div>

        <p class="help-block">The case study will be used in two ways and consent of author is required for both.</p>    
        </div>  

        <br><br>

<input class="submit btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</div>  

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, any other idea?

Comment: What is the filename where your accessing  your data

Comment: it's in folder PHP/submit-test.php, however when I put required in <input class="textboxstyle" type="text" name="Title" required=""> upon clicking submit it wants me to fill the field but wont submit it. (main file is index.php)

Comment: Care to explain what you updated? Code only answers are not good.

Comment: I removed `form` name because it was appearing on both form and submit button